# GitLab API /issues_statistics returns 404

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

GitLab API `/issues_statistics` ( https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues_statistics.html ) for GitLab 11 on-prem returns 404. Is there any settings to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to enable the API. Since you're getting a 404 this is likely an authorization/authentication problem. From the [documentation you linked](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues_statistics.html):

> If a user is not a member of a project and the project is private, a GET request on that project will result to a 404 status code.

If you still have problems, please share the exact endpoint you're trying to use and make sure you're using the right personal access token.